# How can I strengthen an extra wide desk?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

I am planning to build a desk that is nearly 12 feet wide to support 3 computers. There will be two cabinets on both ends, and if possible I would prefer to not need a 3rd cabinet or post in the middle to support it from sagging. Below is a picture similar to what I would like to accomplish.

What techniques could I use to strengthen the top of the desk?

[image]

Comment: This question comes up often. Have you read any of the other answers? [1](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/how-can-i-support-a-desk-without-legs-or-brackets), [2](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29056/how-do-i-build-the-support-structure-for-a-36x14-built-in-desk), [3](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101288/how-to-float-a-large-desk-3000mm-x-720mm-x-40mm-between-walls)

Comment: The strength in a desk like that comes from the supports that are built into the wall. For hidden supports like in the photo, they have to be planned when the wall goes up (or you need to pull the sheetrock down). You'd typically be using larger steel angles and then the desk would 'slip over' them.

Comment: No I haven't. Thanks, I'll take a look at those.

Comment: One more: [4](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/65906/floating-wall-mounted-office-desk?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @DA01 I don't agree they need to go in pre-sheetrock.  You can find the joists and screw into the joists.  It'll be ugly, but put the ugly below the desk and then put a false wall in front of the ugly.  Or shoot, some fabric thumbtacked onto the bottom of the desk.

Comment: @Harper of course, but then they're not hidden like the photos. I would argue if one is going for the above look, they might as well go all-out. :)

Comment: Did someone build that room intentionally to look like that?!?